# Javascript checkboxes and random list outputting text rather than variable

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to make checkboxes page determine what choices are used in the frame.  The lists are just temporary for me to test and the alert(finalchoice) is also just for me to see what gets spit out at the end.  The problem is that, for example, var finalchoice ='choice0' rather than 'http://www.nordstrom.com'.
I feel like this is a simple fix, but I can't figure it out.

```
function myfucntion(){
var final_list = []     
var checkboxes = document.getElementsByClassName('c');    
for (var i = 0; i < checkboxes.length; i++) {

        final_list = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < checkboxes.length; i++) {
            if (checkboxes[i].checked) {
                final_list.push(['choice'+i]);


            }

    };
}

list0  = ['http://www.nordstrom.com','http://www.nordstom.com'];    
list1 = ['http://www.bing.com','http://www.bing.com'];
list2 = ['http://www.yahoo.com','http://www.yahoo.com'];    
list3 = ['http://www.amazon.com','http://www.amazon.com'];

var choice0  = list1[Math.floor(Math.random()*list1.length)];
var choice1  = list2[Math.floor(Math.random()*list2.length)];
var choice2  = list3[Math.floor(Math.random()*list3.length)];
var choice3  = list4[Math.floor(Math.random()*list4.length)];



var finalchoice = final_list[Math.floor(Math.random()*final_list.length)];
document.getElementById('window').src=finalchoice;
alert(finalchoice)    
}
```

Heres the html:

```
<div>
<button onclick="myfunction()">myfunction</button>
</div>
<div>
<input type="checkbox" class="c" />
<input type="checkbox" class="c" />
<input type="checkbox" class="c" />
<input type="checkbox" class="c" />
</div>
<iframe style="width:100%;height:500px" id="window" name="window" src="">
</iframe>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for (var i = 0; i < checkboxes.length; i++) {

    final_list = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < checkboxes.length; i++) {
        if (checkboxes[i].checked) {
            final_list.push(['choice'+i]);


        }
    }
}
```

This nested loop is completely redundant and probably a copypaste error on your part?

```
var final_list = []     
var checkboxes = document.getElementsByClassName('c');    
for (var i = 0; i < checkboxes.length; i++) {
    if (checkboxes[i].checked) {
        final_list.push(['choice'+i]);
    }
}

var finalchoice = final_list[Math.floor(Math.random()*final_list.length)];
document.getElementById('window').src=finalchoice;
alert(finalchoice);
```

> The problem is that, for example, var finalchoice ='choice0' rather than 'http://www.nordstrom.com'

final_list is an array of strings, eg ['choice0', 'choice3', 'choice4'] - not variables.

Even though your question is poorly worded, I feel like what you're trying to do is push variables onto final_list such that you can modify them later.

```
function myfunction() {
    list0  = ['http://www.nordstrom.com','http://www.nordstom.com'];    
    list1 = ['http://www.bing.com','http://www.bing.com'];
    list2 = ['http://www.yahoo.com','http://www.yahoo.com'];    
    list3 = ['http://www.amazon.com','http://www.amazon.com'];

    var choice = [];
    choice[0] = list0[Math.floor(Math.random()*list0.length)];
    choice[1] = list1[Math.floor(Math.random()*list1.length)];
    choice[2] = list2[Math.floor(Math.random()*list2.length)];
    choice[3] = list3[Math.floor(Math.random()*list3.length)];

    var final_list = [];
    var checkboxes = document.getElementsByClassName('c');
    for (var i = 0; i < checkboxes.length; i++) {
        if (checkboxes[i].checked) {
            final_list.push(choice[i]);
        }
    }

    var finalchoice = final_list[Math.floor(Math.random()*final_list.length)];
    document.getElementById('window').src=finalchoice;
    alert(finalchoice);
}
```

Edit: some explanation for your benefit.
First, you were originally trying to push strings onto final_list. Strings are not and cannot be converted to a similarly named variable (without the use of [eval()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_eval.asp) which you should probably try and avoid). To solve this we use an array with indices instead.

Secondly I swapped the loop and the choice[] declarations - when you assign the value of a variable to something you are only assigning a copy of the value. Any future changes will not change that.

Also, please read http://sscce.org/ and make sure that the code you supply is actually compilable. There were many syntax and spelling errors as well as some indenting issues.